# Moderator has moved a discussion to chat - and swept my non-discussion comment with it

Tags: discussion, comments, move-to-chat

I made a comment on a post with many comments. Most of these comments were a sort of a discussion among commenters (well, arguably). Mine, though, did not refer to other comments, but rather directly to the answer.

Now my comment sits in chat, out-of-context, and no-one will read it...

I don't want to make a fuss about this, since it's just a comment after all. So should I just let it go, or rather - make a similar comment, perhaps more briefly, on the original question? And perhaps delete my migrated comment in the chat?

Comment: This is an unavoidable consequence of the "move comments to chat" feature: we cannot selectively move individual comments to chat. It's all or nothing. For me in particular, I will only use this feature as a last resort, such as when the discussion just gets too noisy to ever be useful to anyone. But I do use it, when I need to and there are legitimate comments that get swept away with the rest of the noise.

Comment: @CodyGray: Isn't it possible to move only the "discussion-thread-like" comments to chat?

Comment: No. As I said, moving comments to chat is all or nothing.

Comment: @CodyGray True, but you're not telling them the whole story: after moving to chat all comments, mods can also undelete comments that are worth keeping under the question. Indeed one may simply not notice that a certain comment is worth keeping.

Comment: You can, @Massimo, but that comment will then appear in two places: chat *and* underneath the question. Additionally, doing this requires a *lot* more effort than Stack Overflow moderators are willing to devote to a single Q&A with a large number of noisy comments, given that every day, we usually get over a dozen such flags, in addition to our usual load.

Answer (score 13):

Comments are a Zen exercise, at least on this network. They come, they go. Do not attach yourself to them.

If you consider your content "worthy" to stay on that question/answer then *the answer* is to "dig deeper" and to identify enough more helpful information so that you can submit your input as another answer that (also) addresses the original question, instead of writing a shorter, less detailed comment.

Of course, the final result might be subjective and you might see mixed reception for your comment answer.

Answer (score 8):

It is also a way to *archive* comments that have some degree of value. Comments are never meant to be permanent, and their transience is by design.

If its important, it should probably be better off fleshed out as an answer.

I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: 1. How does moving comments to chat archive them? Doesn't it do the opposite of that? 2. Many comments are supposed to be permanent (unless incorporated into the answer). 3. A comment can be important, but at the same time not an answer. Specifically: It could be a suggestion that the answer should be reconsidered/rephrased.

Comment: @einpoklum Chat is more permanent than comments are, so no, it isn't the opposite of archiving.

Comment: Comments can be deleted and are gone forever. Chat is archived and is always there.

Comment: @einpoklum Sure, chat is less visible than comments. But diligent readers will investigate stuff moved to chat, I always do. And while chat has its downsides (eg, no builtin support for MathJax), it does have some nice features, eg threaded replies, and one-boxing of images and linked posts. And you can chat in rooms on sites where you aren't a member. I wish it were possible for regular members to trigger the "move to chat" feature.

Comment: @PM2Ring: To be honest, I hadn't realized chats are archived - especially not question-specific chats rather than the stable chatrooms.

Comment: @einpoklum "*Many comments are supposed to be permanent."* Comments are ***never*** supposed to be permanent. Their ephemeral status has always been communicated.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Let me rephrase that. The contents of many comments is such that would fit them existing permanently rather than temporarily.

Comment: Then they should be answers. Moving to chat lets us clean up the comments and declutter the post without totally losing that information.... Which should not rely on comments being left around...